# How to use #each to #link-to a specific category in fixture data. Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I'm new to Ember.js and struggling. How would I go about displaying content that is categorized as 'Code'?

```
var posts = [{
    category: 'Code',
    id: 'cssbestpractices',
    title: "CSS Best Practices",
    date: { weekday: "Friday", month: "November", day: "1", year: "2013" }
}, {
    category: 'Code',
    id: 'namingfiles',
    title: "Naming Files",
    date: { weekday: "Thursday", month: "October", day: "24", year: "2013" }
}, {
    category: 'Pizza',
    id: 'seo-copy-block',
    title: "SEO Copy Block",
    date: { weekday: "Tuesday", month: "November", day: "5", year: "2013" }
}];
```

I would think I could do something as simple as...

```
{{#each posts is category.Code}}
  <li>{{#link-to 'post' this}}{{title}}{{/link-to}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

...but I must be missing something. My google searches haven't been successful since I'm not good with Ember.js terminology. Here is where I am at in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/builtbymay/7BEyX/) ([and full page view](http://fiddle.jshell.net/builtbymay/7BEyX/show/light/)). I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: This works for me. What exactly is not working the way you like? Looks like you might have figured it out since posting this.

Comment: @RHollister I'm looking for it to list only those categorized with Code and not Pizza.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [filterBy](http://emberjs.com/api/#method_computed_filterBy) computed macro to do this:

```
App.PostsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    codePosts: Ember.computed.filterBy('model', 'category', 'Code')
});
```

Your updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/BZwQL/

Comment: Thank you and thanks for introducing me to filterBy!

Comment: You are welcome! filterBy is awesome, there is others good computed macros, just give a look in all the Ember.computed.*.